# Is there a way to make doxygen use pandoc as the markdown parser?

Tags: latex, doxygen, pandoc

Can I make doxygen use pandoc to prepare the markdown files for inclusion in the doxygen latex? I like how pandoc supports more features for writing chapters than the built-in one. Such as the differint table styles, and more features when it comes to formatting.